# Django - How to access the same list on every call to views.py?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game with Python (Django). It will be just a 3x3 table.

When user clicks on a cell - Ajax call to a specific url that leads to views.py.
Do I need to send values of the all cells to python script every time?
Or is there a way to declare a list with all values inside views.py and access it every time when the call is made?

Comment: it's just a decision and also related to your API architecture. I suggest you read about [stateless and stateful application](https://nordicapis.com/defining-stateful-vs-stateless-web-services/).

Comment: I really liked Gregor Riegler explanation, guess I will just reread the table every time and send it to views.py instead of using sessions. Thanks!